# jQuery Breaks My Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I wrote a page using asp.net with a bunch of jquery code to automate different parts of the interaction on the page.

Whenever the jquery fails for whatever reason, the rest of the page stops functioning properly. Click events stop functioning, selection triggers stop functioning, checkbox trigers stop firing.

Do i need to wrap every single jquery function in a try catch block to avoid this or what is the best practice to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you wrapping your jQuery code in a $(function() {}); block? That way it wont try and wire up your jQuery code until the page is ready.

Comment: yes most of the code is wrapped up in functions. I am trying to use a modular design and have the code split into its own file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple google search will give you some blog posts to get started such as [javascript error handling](https://www.sitepoint.com/proper-error-handling-javascript/)

Then its a matter of picking through the different opinions and working out what is best for your situation.  Personally, I first try to avoid exceptions occurring in the first place with defensive coding. In cases where a possible exception cant be avoided and the user can do something about it (such as retry) then I will handle the specific exception at that point in the code.  In cases where it is an unexpected exception and it would leave the app in a broken state then I would let the exception bubble to a global handler, log the error and redirect the user to an error page.

Answer (score 0):

No

```
On Error Resume Next
```

like  stuff does not work in javascript/jQuery, it is recommended to put your code in `try/catch` block.

Another DOM level approach (though not ideal):

```
window.onerror = function(){
   return true;
}
```

Comment: the jquery stuff stops working and also the rest of the elements on the page stop responding.

Comment: Please put Try/Catch in your code functions. Use Developer Tools (  browser F12) to check the error line number and put try/catch. Does window.error make to trick ?

Comment: that did not fix my problem.